# Highcharts Tooltip not rendering properly if it has material icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, tooltip, google-material-icons

In my rails application I have a graph with icons generated with Highcharts.
The icons are Google Material design icons that I get through a material-icons gem. https://github.com/Angelmmiguel/material_icons.

I want to do 2 things with the icons:

1. Instead of numeric labels I want smileys. This I got working

   ```
   yAxis: {
           max: 5,
           min: 1,
           labels: {
               formatter: function () {
                   if (this.value == 1) {
                       return '<i class="material-icons">sentiment_very_dissatisfied</i>'
                   }
                   if (this.value == 2) {
                       return '<i class="materialicons">sentiment_dissatisfied</i>'
                   }
                   if (this.value == 3) {
                       return '<i class="material-icons" height="5px">sentiment_neutral</i>'
                   }
                   if (this.value == 4) {
                       return '<i class="material-icons">sentiment_satisfied</i>'
                   }
                   if (this.value == 5) {
                       return '<i class="material-icons">sentiment_very_satisfied</i>'
                   } else {
                       return this.value
                   }
               }
           }
       },
   ```

   [image]
2. Instead of numeric values in the tooltip I want smileys. This is where it goes wrong.

   ```
   tooltip: {
           formatter: function () {
               var date = Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m-%y %H:%M',
                   new Date(this.x));
               var getIcon = function (y) {
                   if (y == 1) {
                       return '<i class="material-icons">sentiment_very_dissatisfied</i>'
                   }
                   if (y == 2) {
                       return '<i class="material-icons">sentiment_dissatisfied</i>'
                   }
                   if (y == 3) {
                       return '<i class="material-icons">sentiment_neutral</i>'
                   }
                   if (y == 4) {
                       return '<i class="material-icons">sentiment_satisfied</i>'
                   }
                   if (y == 5) {
                       return '<i class="material-icons">sentiment_very_satisfied</i>'
                   } else {
                       return y
                   }
               };
               var icon = getIcon(this.y);
               console.log(date);
               return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + date + ' : ' + icon;
           },
   ```

   I have to parse the date because it is a JavaScript epoch time(milliseconds). Without `+ icon` the date is shown. If I add `+ icon` it doesn't work and the date will not correctly render. What I noticed is that the icon is higher than the line itself. So I think this is a CSS problem, but I don't know how to fix it.
   Without:[image: without]With:[image: with]

Thanks in advance for replying!

Comment: Try enabling html in a tooltip. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML
Usually an undesired line appears if the data is not sorted ascending, so make sure your data is in correct order. Check the console log for the errors.

Comment: @morganfree How could I be so stupid by not trying that.. The smileys are working right now. I found out that the data set was not correct after I posted the question. Please give this as your answer so I can close my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using HTML in a tooltip, enable [tooltip.useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML) property.

```
 tooltip: {
        useHTML: true
```

Also, the data must be sorted in ascending order, otherwise undesired graphical shapes might occur in a chart.